# SharePoint Online Lists - Conditional Formatting to hide columns in form - not working

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, list-form, json-formatting

Trying to use nested conditional formatting to hide columns depending on other values, which was working in the local List that I built but won't work online and running around in circles trying to figure it out.

```
=(if[$Type] == 'Property', 'false', if [$Numbers] >= 2, 'true', 'false')
```

Any assistance is much appreciated.

Comment: Hi @Danj, Please [Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) & [accept my reply as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) as it helped you & it will help others with similar question in future. It also removes this question from "Unanswered Questions" list.

Answer (score 2):

I can see you missed few parentheses in your formula. Try using this formula:

```
=if([$Type] == 'Property', 'false', if ([$Numbers] >= 2, 'true', 'false'))
```

**Note**: The column is represented by specifying the **internal name** of the field surrounded by square brackets and preceded by a dollar sign: `[$InternalName]`. For example, to get the value of a field with an internal name of "ProductName", use `[$ProductName]`.

You can get the internal name of your column by following this article: [How to find the Internal name of columns in SharePoint Online?](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2023/04/17/how-to-find-the-internal-name-of-sharepoint-columns/)

**Documentation**: [Show or hide columns in a list or library form](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/list-form-conditional-show-hide)

---

As per the comments by @theChrisKent below, this formula could be shortened to:

```
=[$Type]!='Property' && [$Numbers]>=2
```

Comment: This can be shortened to `=[$Type]=='Property' || [$Numbers]>=2`

Comment: @theChrisKent when `[$Type] == 'Property'`, field should be hidden & when `[$Numbers] >= 2`, field should be shown on the form.

Comment: Whoops! Then it could be shortened to `=[$Type]!='Property' && [$Numbers]>=2`